# SELECT WHERE = sybol dont return data

Tags: php, sqlite

a have an sqlite table

```sql
CREATE TABLE "lib" (
    "id"    INTEGER UNIQUE,
    "addr"  TEXT UNIQUE,
    "data"  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
)
```

testing dataset contains:

```
...
1   arara       arararar test
2   unit=comp   comp test
...
```

I use code next to test requests

```php
<? $db = new PDO('sqlite:main.db') or die('Unable to open database');

echo ("qry: ".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]."<br>");
foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM lib WHERE addr='".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]."'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC/*_NUM*/) as $row) {
    //echo($row[0].'<br>');
    echo($row['addr'].'<br>');
    echo($row['data'].'<br>');
}

$db = null; ?>
```

so, when I do `script.php?arara` it returns

```
qry: arara
arara
arararar test
```

but, when I do `script.php?unit=comp` it returns no data (just QUERY_STRING)

```
qry: unit=comp
```

what wrong with my code?

upd:

1. *this question is not about security*
2. php modified for PDO prepare, now its return no data with any request

```php
<? $db = new PDO('sqlite:main.db') or die('Unable to open database');

echo ("qry: ".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]."<br>");

$qry=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM lib WHERE addr='?'");
$qry->execute(array($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]));
foreach ($qry as $row) {
//foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM lib WHERE addr='".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]."'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC/*_NUM*/) as $row) {
    //echo($row[0].'<br>');
    echo($row['addr'].'<br>');
    echo($row['data'].'<br>');
}

$db = null; ?>
```

Comment: use `urlencode($QueyString)` before send to query string parameter then pass after use `urldecode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])` while get parameter

Comment: i checked, string passes to query() correct
`SELECT * FROM lib WHERE addr='unit=comp'`

Comment: **Everything** is wrong with your code. `echo` is not a function, so you don't need parentheses. `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` does not make sense to be injected into SQL. Avoid SQL injection. Use paramterized prepared statemenets. I doubt this would ever execute `or die('Unable to open database')`

Comment: @Dharman I modified php for PDO prepare; at this variant any request return no data

Comment: Please [edit] the question with updated code.

Comment: done, pasted new variant

Comment: @jameson2012 i really dont understand what you mean. have you ideas how to modify .php to make it able get data from db that contains "="?

Answer (score 1):

> what wrong with my code?

... sadly quite a lot.

I've never seen someone inject the `QUERY_STRING` straight into a query.  How easily corruptable would this string be?  If I wanted to inject some malicious sql I just have to write it in.  If I make a mistake then the query won't return anything.  If I add a new parameter in the future because I want more than a single param then the query fails.

The malicious sql is the most dangerous problem here, the other's are about code maintainability and still very important.  Check out this

https://bobby-tables.com/
and this
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

You need to parse the query string so you can check and sanitise the data.  Php has an in-built function for this:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

You then should be binding the data in the prepared statement you have now read about.

I don't know if you're in charge of the script calling this, but it seems like POST data would be better for this.  GET parameters are visible and stored in web server logs, so you have a security vulnerability with potential personal data.  You also then won't need to worry about url_encoding/decoding the string.

//EDIT

to be fair, using PHP's `parse_str` with decode the url anyway, so that at least will take care of that issue if you can't convert it to post

Comment: my question is not about security, you may see that    

>>I use code next to **test** requests    

but i need solution to trouble with "=" in this case

Comment: i modified php for PDO prepare; at this variant any request return no data